# Set of lower bounds not containing a greatest member

Tags: analysis, supremum-and-infimum

The Wikipedia page for Supremum and Infimum contains this quote.

> Infima and suprema do not necessarily exist. Existence of an infimum of a subset **S** of **P** can fail if **S** has no lower bound at all, or if the set of lower bounds does not contain a greatest element. However, if an infimum or supremum does exist, it is unique.

I understand how a suprema cannot exist in the example set **S1** containing all natural numbers or how infima cannot exist in the example set **S2** containing all rational numbers. But the next sentence,

> if the set of lower bounds does not contain a greatest element

doesn't make sense to me. How can a set not contain a greatest element? This doesn't mean some kind of 2D vector space like the complex numbers (where there is no natural ordering), does it? What would be an example of a set that has no infima or suprema for *this* reason rather than the much more easy to understand "no lower bound" reason?

I've not formally studied Analysis so I would appreciate a more "simple" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to read a little further in the article:

> As an example, let $S$ be the set of all finite subsets of natural numbers and consider the partially ordered set obtained by taking all sets from $S$ together with the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ and the set of positive real numbers $\mathbb{R} ^+$, ordered by subset inclusion [as above]. Then clearly both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}^+$ are greater than all finite sets of natural numbers. Yet, neither is $\mathbb{R}^+$ smaller than $\mathbb{Z}$ nor is the converse true: both sets are minimal upper bounds but none is a supremum.

The problem is that for *partially* ordered sets different upper bounds may not be comparable. If your set is totally ordered, such as $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$, then there is no issue. Or in other words, such examples can only happen in sets that are not totally ordered.